# Deploying Keras Model in web app with real time plots using plotly

Tags: python, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I’ve developed a deep learning model using keras and I’ve successfully deployed it in a flash app. In contains a /predict endpoint that another application can query with data and then get a prediction returned to it. This flask app simply runs as a console application, but in addition to that I also wanted to pop up a web page that shows a real time scatter plot of the input data. I was able to do this using the bokeh library and marrying that into my flask app. Now, when the app launches, a web page of the plot is opened and it is configured to hit a new ‘/data’ endpoint in the flask app periodically to get the latest data and update the 2d scatter plot. This seems to be working reliably.

Now for the reason for my post. I would really like to improve upon this by changing my 2d scatter plot to a 3d scatter plot. Unfortunately, bokeh does not offer a 3d scatter plot out of the box. This brought me to plotly and dash. I know plotly can do a 3d scatter plot. I’m looking for sample code, or advice on how I should go about doing this.

Should I keep the existing structure of a flask app but somehow combine that with plotly to take the place of bokeh? This means plotly would have to create the web page and periodically hit the /data enpoint of my flask app.

Should I abandon flask and change to a dash app? If so, I would then need to deploy a keras model in dash. and setup both the /predict and /data enpoints.

Below is my existing code with flask and bokeh. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should proceed and even better, can anyone show me some sample code that would be applicable to what I’m trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import model_from_json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import AjaxDataSource, CustomJS, Range1d

# Bokeh related code

adapter = CustomJS(code="""
    const result = {x: [], y: []}
    const pts = cb_data.response.points
    for (i=0; i<pts.length; i++) {
        result.x.push(pts[i][0])
        result.y.push(pts[i][1])
    }
    return result
""")

source = AjaxDataSource(data_url='http://10.61.226.215:443/data',
                        polling_interval=200, adapter=adapter)

p = figure(plot_height=700, plot_width=1400, x_axis_label='Frequency', y_axis_label='Phase', background_fill_color="lightgrey",
           title="Scatter Plot of TOI")
p.x_range = Range1d(0, 49)
p.y_range = Range1d(-2**15, 2**15)
p.circle('x', 'y', source=source, color='red', size=10)

# Flask related code

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_model():
    global model
    global g

    json_path = 'RNN_LSTM_128_Drop0p2.json'
    h5_path = "RNN-010-0.983732-0.997119.h5"
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default():
        # Pull in the model we want to test
        json_file = open(json_path, 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
        # load weights into new model
        model.load_weights(h5_path)
        print("Loaded model from disk")
        # Compile the loaded model
        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                      optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
        print("Compiled Model")
    print(" * Recurrent Neural Network Trained Model Loaded Successfully")


def RNN_scale_input(X):
    N_samp = X.shape[0]
    N_t_samp = X.shape[1]
    n_feat = X.shape[2]

    X_scale = np.zeros(shape=(N_samp, N_t_samp, n_feat), dtype=np.float32)
    for h in range(N_samp):
        # Scale the channel index to be between -1 and 1
        X_scale[h][:, 0] = (X[h][:, 0] - 25) / 25
        # Scale the phase value to be between -1 and 1
        X_scale[h][:, 1] = X[h][:, 1] / 2**15
    return X_scale


# Define function to pre-process phase data
def pre_process_data(data, num_rows, num_cols):
    # Strip the opening and closing brackets from the input data string
    data = data.strip('[]')
    # Convert string into a list of floating point numbers
    try:
        data = [float(h) for h in data.split(',')]
    except:
        print("***ERROR***")
        print(data)
    data_np = np.asarray(data).reshape(1, num_rows, num_cols)
    rnn_structure = RNN_scale_input(data_np)
    return rnn_structure[0]

def pre_process_plot_data(data, num_rows, num_cols):
    # Strip the opening and closing brackets from the input data string
    data = data.strip('[]')
    # Convert string into a list of floating point numbers
    try:
        list_data = [int(k) for k in data.split(',')]
    except:
        print("***ERROR***")
        print(data)
    plot_data_np = np.asarray(list_data).reshape(num_rows, num_cols)
    return plot_data_np


N_t, n_features = 64, 2
print(" * Loading Neural Network Trained Model...")
get_model()

# Define Tag of Interest to plot
TOI = "307401320416C2054B6E99D7"

def crossdomain(f):
    def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
        resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
        h = resp.headers
        h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "GET, OPTIONS, POST"
        h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(21600)
        requested_headers = request.headers.get('Access-Control-Request-Headers')
        if requested_headers:
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = requested_headers
        return resp
    return wrapped_function


x = [0]*N_t
y = [0]*N_t

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    global x
    global y
    message = request.get_json(force=True)
    TagId = message['TagId']
    PhaseData = message['PhaseInput']
    model_input = np.zeros(shape=(1, N_t, n_features), dtype='float32')
    model_input[0] = pre_process_data(PhaseData, N_t, n_features)
    # If TagId == TOI, plot the data
    if TagId == TOI:
        # Update data in plot
        plot_data = pre_process_plot_data(PhaseData, N_t, n_features)
        x1 = list(plot_data[:, 0])
        x = [int(x1[i]) for i in range(N_t)]
        y1 = list(plot_data[:, 1])
        y = [int(y1[i]) for i in range(N_t)]

    # Make prediction with model
    with g.as_default():
        model_output = model.predict(model_input)
    # Take the second element (location at index (0, 1)) as the float prediction
    pred_val = model_output[0, 1]
    prediction = pred_val.tolist()
    # Construct response to send back to client app
    response = {
        'tag': TagId,
        'prediction': prediction
    }
    return jsonify(response)


@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'])
@crossdomain
def data():
    global x
    global y
    return jsonify(points=list(zip(x, y)))

# show and run
show(p)
# app.run(port=443)
```